# Connect-AzAccount error when running Azure Functions coded in PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I am getting this error when trying to run my Azure Function (Which is in PowerShell). PowerShell script works normally when ran locally.

Error:

```
[Error] ERROR: No subscription found in the context.  Please ensure that the credentials you provided are authorized to access an Azure subscription, then run Connect-AzAccount to login
```

In `requirements.ps1`:

```
@{
    'Az.Accounts' = '1.9.0'
    'Az.Resources' = '1.1.2'
    'AzTable' = '2.0.3'
    'Az.Storage' = '1.7.0'
    'Az.KeyVault' = '1.5.1'
}
```

In the `run.ps1`, I added the `Import-Module` commands:

```
Import-Module Az.Resources
Import-Module Az.Accounts
Import-Module Az.KeyVault
Import-Module AzTable
```

First few lines in '`run.ps1`':

```
$activeKey = Get-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $storageAccountName

# Get Storage Account Key 
$key = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $storageAccountName)
```

In `profile.ps1`:

```
if ($env:MSI_SECRET) {
    Disable-AzContextAutosave
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure you:

1. [Enable a managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity). Using a system-assigned identity is easier, using a user-assigned identity requires [one more step](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5797#issuecomment-601864473).
2. [Assign appropriate roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal#add-a-role-assignment-for-a-managed-identity-preview) on the target subscription to the identity.
3. In your `run.ps1` code, invoke `Set-AzContext` to select the target subscription.

Importing modules explicitly in `run.ps1` is usually not necessary.

Comment: Hey thanks. Really close now. Currently getting a different error "[Error] ERROR: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'Exception             :Type       : Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorExceptionRequest".  

I tried to give Key Vault rights to the Function App, Access Policies to the Key Vault but still to no avail. Any ieda?